# Mockito Test Framework WantedButNotInvoked Exception

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to Write Testcases for the A method that is `handleFault` method of the `soaphandller` in that we are getting object of the `SOAPMessageContext` interface object from that I have to get the `SOAPFault` object and after getting object I have to get all its property and I have to create a customize Exception class and set the `SOAPFault` object property into the Exception class object and throw that Exception Class object from that method .

My source code which is `CVOSSecurityHandller` method

```
  public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
      try {
        Iterator iterator;      
        SOAPFault fault=context.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault();
        SoapServiceException serviceException=new SoapServiceException();
    serviceException.setDetail(fault.getDetail());
        serviceException.setFaultActor(fault.getFaultActor());
        iterator=fault.getAllAttributes();
    List<Name> faultAllAttribute=new ArrayList<Name>();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            faultAllAttribute.add((Name)iterator.next());
        }
        serviceException.setFaultAllAttribute(faultAllAttribute);
        serviceException.setFaultCode(fault.getFaultCode());
        serviceException.setFaultCodeName(fault.getFaultCodeAsName());
        serviceException.setFaultCodeQName(fault.getFaultCodeAsQName());
        serviceException.setFaultNode(fault.getFaultNode());
        serviceException.setFaultRole(fault.getFaultRole());
        serviceException.setFaultString(fault.getFaultString());
        iterator=fault.getFaultReasonTexts();
        List<String> faultReasons=new ArrayList<String>();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            faultReasons.add((String)iterator.next());
        }
        serviceException.setFaultReasons(faultReasons);
        List<QName> faultSubcode=new ArrayList<QName>();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        faultSubcode.add((QName)iterator.next());
        }
    throw serviceException;
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
  }
```

MY Customize Exception class

```
public class SoapServiceException extends RuntimeException {
  private Detail detail;
  private String faultActor;
  private String faultCode;
  private Name faultCodeName;
  private QName faultCodeQName;
  private String faultNode;
  private String faultRole;
  private String faultString;
  private List<QName> faultSubcode;
  private List<Name> faultAllAttribute;
  private List<String> faultReasons;

// here is getter and setter of above properties
}
```

My Test case file which makes for test the HandleFault method

```
public class CVOSSecurityHandllerTest {
    private CVOSSecurityHandler mockCvosSecurityHandller=mock(CVOSSecurityHandler.class);
    private SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext=mock(SOAPMessageContext.class);
    private SOAPMessage soapMessage =mock(SOAPMessage.class);
    private SOAPBody soapBody=mock(SOAPBody.class);
    private SOAPFault soapFault=mock(SOAPFault.class);
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        Factory.instance = new Factory(new MockServicesModule());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
    }
    @Test(expected=SoapServiceException.class)
    public void testHandleFault(){
        try{

        when(soapMessageContext.getMessage()).thenReturn(soapMessage);
            when(soapMessage.getSOAPBody()).thenReturn(soapBody);
            when(soapBody.addFault()).thenReturn(soapFault);
            when(soapFault.getFaultString()).thenReturn("The fault string");
            verify(this.mockCvosSecurityHandller, atLeastOnce()).handleFault(soapMessageContext);
            reset(this.mockCvosSecurityHandller);

        }
        catch(SOAPException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            //throw new SoapServiceException();
        }
        catch(SoapServiceException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.assertEquals("The fault",e.getFaultString());
        }


    }
    @BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
{
    }

    private class MockServicesModule extends AbstractModule
    {

        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
            bind(SOAPMessageContext.class).toInstance(CVOSSecurityHandllerTest.this.soapMessageContext);
            bind(SOAPMessage.class).toInstance(CVOSSecurityHandllerTest.this.soapMessage);
            bind(SOAPBody.class).toInstance(CVOSSecurityHandllerTest.this.soapBody);
            bind(SOAPFault.class).toInstance(CVOSSecurityHandllerTest.this.soapFault);
        }
    }


}
```

So please help me out that where am I commiting mistake and provide the possible solution for that. I am trying to create mock object

```
CVOSSecurityHandler mockCvosSecurityHandller=mock(CVOSSecurityHandler.class);
private SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext=mock(SOAPMessageContext.class);
private SOAPMessage soapMessage =mock(SOAPMessage.class);
private SOAPBody soapBody=mock(SOAPBody.class);
private SOAPFault soapFault=mock(SOAPFault.class);
```

And verfiy the mock object of the `CVOSSecurityHandller` and call the `handleFault` method but it throws Exception of the `WantedButNotInvoked`.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your real object instance?  All I see are mocks.   Your system-under-test (i.e., class under test) should be a real object rather than a mock, otherwise none of your real code will be executed.

Comment: Hello Kevin
can you please elobrate it.
can you please tell where am i wrong.

Thanks

Comment: @user1544283 - I think Kevin said it quite clearly.  DON'T mock the class that you're actually testing; use a real object, otherwise there's nothing to test (remember that a mock is basically an object with all the functionality stripped out).  The whole point of mocking is to take OTHER classes out of the equation - that is, if you replace all the collaborator objects with mocks, then the behaviour of the collaborator classes won't interfere with your tests.  (In this context, collaborator objects are objects that the object that you're testing interacts with).

Comment: In particular, do not mock CVOSSecurityHandler, since that is the class containing the code you want to test.  Beyond that, there appear to be several other practices both in your code and test code that are not very optimal.  But start with the basics: you first need to understand why you absolutely should *never* mock the class under test.  On rare occasions, there might be a need to @Spy it, but never mock.  After you figure that out and try it, you'll probably have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for giving me answer ,I have got solution